# Illegal pream-token (\frac): `c' used

Tags: math-mode, equations, latex3

I was inserting an equation in my Latex code but it's appearing as a problem.

I was trying to create a system of 2 equations but the problem keeps appearing and I don't know why

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}
        \frac{d\vec{x}_P}{dt}(t) = \vec{u}_P(\vec{x}_{str}(t), t)\\
        \vec{x}_{str}(t = \tau) = \vec{x}_{P0}
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Hope you can help, thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use something like `\begin{align*}` instead?

Comment: you need `\begin{array}{c}` as you have a one-column centred table, but do not use `array` for displayed equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `array` is throwing an error because you didn't specify an alignment. If we set the alignment to `l` for left-align, for example, then it compiles fine:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{l}
        \frac{d\vec{x}_P}{dt}(t) = \vec{u}_P(\vec{x}_{str}(t), t)\\
        \vec{x}_{str}(t = \tau) = \vec{x}_{P0}
    \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: OP's system of equations left-aligned]

Like @dg said in the comments, there are better ways to typeset systems of equations depending on how you want them to look. I personally use `cases` from `amsmath`, but I'll leave that discussion to others in the comments.

Also, the `_{str}` subscript should really be something like `_{\mathrm{str}}` instead. The latter is treated as text and is styled as such, while the former is just a sequence of variables and won't always be kerned correctly.

Comment: `\mathrm` would be better than `\text`

Comment: And `cases` would add unwanted horizontal space, failing to center the object.

Answer (score 2):

`array` requires an argument where you specify the column types. In your case a single column `l`eft aligned.

But that's not the right tool for the purpose. Consult the manual of `amsmath` for better choices. Here I recommend `aligned` (or `split`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

You're missing the column specification for \texttt{array}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
  \frac{d\vec{x}_P}{dt}(t) = \vec{u}_P(\vec{x}_{str}(t), t)\\
  \vec{x}_{str}(t = \tau) = \vec{x}_{P_0}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
but you can do much better with \texttt{aligned}
and \verb+\mathrm{str}+
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{d\vec{x}_P}{dt}(t) = \vec{u}_P(\vec{x}_{\mathrm{str}}(t), t)\\
& \vec{x}_{\mathrm{str}}(t = \tau) = \vec{x}_{P_0}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also fixed `P0` into `P_0`.